# Displaying the webpage in a relativelayout using webview

Tags: android, xml, webview, window

Hello guys this the my xml code i am trying the display the browser in window but its always gets redirected to the browser

**Xml:**

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
</WebView>
```

**Code:**

```
public class Activity_Retailers extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Help me out guys thanks a lot

Comment: Its working code..What is your error? Did you specify the Internet permission in manifest??

Answer (score 0):

Set [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your WebView in java-code and owerride [shouldOwerrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.string.webview);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```